# UV unwrapping Problem

Tags: texturing, uv

I need to UV unwrapping this model and tried many ways to do this but still think should be a better way to do that. any help is appreciated.
the blend file is attached.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, why do you think it's not good? It's seems good, maybe scale it a bit on the X axis to get a more square grid? Also it depends on what you want to do with the UV map

Comment: Hi. with the help of the Ribbit12 I fixed my topology :) I am going to texture this model and the UV should be correct for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HOW TO UNWRAP

STEP 1
add a seam in the middle of your mesh
[image]

and it should unwrap like this
[image]

STEP 2
[image]
You might notice that your Uvs are still distorted and rotated to fix this you will need to download a Uv Square addon from online(free of cost) link is given below.

[UV SQUARE ADDON LINK HERE](https://github.com/Radivarig/UvSquares)
Go to download code > press download file
Then open blender preferences add ons menu and press install
[image]

Then select the zip file that you downloaded from the given link and press install add-on

Now search UV square addon in the addon menu and enable it

[image]

STEP 3

press A to select your mesh in edit mode and select both of your UV islands by pressing A on your keypad . Now open the menu by pressing N and then go to the UV squares tab in your menu and press the options grid by shape and Tada! your Uvs are beautifully clean and straight.

IT SHOULD APPEAR LIKE THIS

[image]

**HOPE THIS HELPED AND WORKED**

Comment: you are the best bro. I am so appreciative of you. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Your welcome really happy to help you

Answer (score 3):

smt I took a look at your project file, found out that your mesh`s geometry is terrible. There are a lot of overlapping edges because of the solidify and subdivision surface modifier. So I think it's best if you add extra edges or subdivisions in the hard areas and scale it and avoiding the subdivision surface modifier as it subdivides areas where there are already a lot of edges and overlaps. Last but least you definitely need to add seams.

**REMEMBER YOU CAN ALWAYS GO AHEAD AND ADD EXTRA EDGE LOOPS MANUALLY BY YOURSELF AND SCALING IT TO SUBDIVIDE RIGID AREAS INSTEAD OF SUBDIVISION SURFACE MODIFIER.**
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
***I JUST MOVED AN EDGE AND THE MESH GOES CRAZY THESE ARE SIGNS OF BAD GEOMETRY***

***SM= subdivision modifier**

***An easy way to clean up your geometry and unnecessary vertices is by pressing A to select your whole mesh in edit mode and press M and merge by distance.***

[image]

Comment: Thank yo so much. your answer was so helpful and I am going to fix my topology. I still have problem with UV. I added the seems like you did but did not work. can you upload your unwrapped model blend file please ?

Comment: I will send a clear explained answer how to uv unwrap really clean in a few minutes

Comment: Thanks you bro 

Comment: happy to help! Your answer is sent

Comment: hi! smt I have made aome changes to your mesh(only the top face) and I have unwrapped it more better by adding some more seams.I could have explained the process but since you asked the file I am just going to send the file to you

Comment: FILE:     https://blend-exchange.com/b/W3eWb05B                      The unwrap is not brilliant but it will do the trick

Comment: NOTE: the end result of the method that you will have followed in here in the solution I have given and the model in the given file are different.